# Fill a textField with a selected TableViewCell?

Tags: swift, xcode6, tableview, textfield, uitableview

In my initial view there is a blank `textField` (with an invisible button over it) that segues to a `TableView` when you click it. I want to send the text data from my `TableViewCell` selection to the blank `textField` in the original view.

I've made a `View2.swift` file, which is a replica of my original `View`. I was trying to edit the source code in there to push the `textData` by sending the `.text` from the `indexPath` of the `TableView`.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guSYMPaXLaw) shows how to send data from a first view to a second view, but I'm trying to send data from my second view (`TableView`) back to my first view (`View`).

Here is my code:

`ViewController.swift`

```
 import UIKit

 class ViewController: UITableViewController {

     override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
         var DestViewController : View2 = segue.destinationViewController as! View2

        DestViewController.formulaSelectionText = ViewController.
     }
 }
```

`View2.swift`:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class View2: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad(){
        formulaSelection.text = indexPathForCell(Cell: UITableView)
    }
}
```

I assume it would be best to just update the value in the initial view. I'm thinking with a `UITextFieldDelegate`?

Comment: write your code snippet here, what have you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to pass back `UITableViewCell` Selected value back to a controller. Simply on selection of a cell, update the textfield's value in previous controller and pop the controller/dismiss it if you are using navigation controller / modal controller.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        //get last controller in hierarchy
        let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController!.viewControllers as [UIViewController];
        var prevController : PrevViewController = viewControllers[viewControllers.count - 1] as PrevViewController;
        prevController.textfield.text = dataSource[indexPath.row]; //update textfield here
        self.navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true);

    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response! This is my first time creating an iOS app, so I have a few more questions. 1) is PrevViewController a class ? Its not coming up in my compiler. 2) This means I need to set my TableView identifier as dataSource in order for the controller to read the data from it, correct?

Comment: 1) I have just named `PrevViewController` for better clarification. It will be replaced by `ViewController` - your first controller swift class. 2) `Tableview` Datasource methods have been implemented in `View2`, since tableview is present there.